# How to show that the dependent variable decreases to a plateau over trials?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, data-visualization, multiple-comparisons

One of my hypotheses is about the dependent variable decreasing to a plateau over trials in control and treatment conditions.

I have a regression model that shows a decrease in the dependent variable over trails. Visually I can show that in both conditions it does reach a plateau, but is there any other more sophisticated statistical method, that can help me show that it reaches a plateau?

Comment: You may want to look at linear-plateau or quadratic-plateau models.  If the data are very messy, Cate-Nelson approach can be helpful.

Comment: @SalMangiafico it's great information,thank you! I have never come across this. The linear plateau one looks like my data. I will take a deeper look in to it.